# Creating Backbone model nested functions

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I've got a Backbone model, with a bunch of functions that I want to add to it. For convenience, I want to split them up into groups.  I want to use them like this:
`modelInstance.group1.foo();` or `modelInstance.group2.bar();` where both `group1.foo` and `group2.bar`'s `this` reference is modelInstance.

I've tried using `_.bindAll(this, 'group1.foo')`, but that didn't work.

How would I change the following to accomplish my goals...if its possible?

```
var group1Funcs = {
        foo: function(){ return this.get("count") + 1;},
        ...
    },
    model = Backbone.Model.extend({
        group1: group1Funcs
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var fns = {
  first: function() {
    console.log(this.vars);
  }
};

var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    this.vars = [ 1, 2 ];
    this.fnGroup = {};
    var self = this;
    _.each(fns, function(fn, key) {
      var nfn = _.bind(fn, self);
      self.fnGroup[key] = nfn;
    });
  },
});

var model = new Model();
model.fnGroup.first() // [ 1, 2 ]
```